# timer in jquark component in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

i am trying to use alert as

```
var timer = document.getElementById('timer') ;
        timer.innerHTML = '<?php echo JText::_('TIME_REMAINING') ; ?> ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds ;


    if( minutes== 29 ){
            alert("5 Minutes Left");

                }
                else
                {
            timer.innerHTML = '<?php echo JText::_('TIME_REMAINING') ; ?> ' + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds ;
                        }
```

But id displaying the `alert` on every `29 minutes`- Basically i am need to display the alert before some minutes with respect to quiz time. whats wrong in that ? `Its a jquark component`- Any help Please ?

Comment: Can you show rest of your code?

Comment: @ woodzu, yes please let me.. VISIT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351495/alert-timer-in-jquarks-component-in-joomla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem, here an `interval` is used to check the remaining time and alert the user.

```
var timeleft = 120000;

var timer = document.getElementById('timer') ;
timer.innerHTML= Math.floor((timeleft/60000)) + ' minutes';

var date  = new Date();
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var diff = d.getTime() - date.getTime();
  if ( diff > timeleft ) {
    alert('done');
    clearInterval(interval);
  }else if ( diff > 60000 ) {
    alert('1 min')
  }
  timer.innerHTML= Math.floor(((timeleft - diff)/60000)) + ' minutes';
}, 60000);
```

You may have to tweak the parameter to suit your needs

Example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m6UQX/1/)